# The mathematical interpretation of DFT

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, linear-algebra

We have the DFT(matrix form) $X = Wx$ ($W$ is the Fourier basis matrix, $x$ is the original signal in time domain, $X$ is in the frequency domain).

In mathematics, $x$ represents the coordinates of $X$ with respect to $W$. I don't know how this happens. I think $x = WX$ is right, because $X$ is in the space spanned by the $W$, thus $x$ is the linear combination of Fourier basis and Fourier coefficients. Thus $x = WX$.

Why is it valid? Can you tell me?

P.S.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGkn-3NFGck&index=32&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8

36''33', Prof. Strang gives a different explanation in wavelet transform, it differs from DFT.. That's why I am confused

Comment: If $X=Wx$, then $x=W^{-1}X$, not $WX$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate The question is, I don't think $X=Wx$ is right.

Comment: that's not a question. $X=Wx$ is obviously right, given that you've defined it.

Comment: $X=Wx$ is defined by Oppenhiem, not me. I could not understand the meaning of it

Comment: It's a definition. We call this the DFT, when $W$ is the DFT matrix. You're overthinking this.

Comment: I can't make head or tail about what your question really is. You seem to be overthinking this as @MarcusMüller says.

Comment: $W$ is the Fourier basis matrix , $x$ is in the standard basis, it seems that $Wx$ would not make sense.@PeterK.

Comment: @PeterK. ok you can be right stander Qui, but only if you replace last $x$ with something else such as $x_2$ (which is not equal to $x$) so that if $X = Wx$ then there exists an $x_2$ such that $x_2 = WX$ where this operation is considered as multiple DFTs operated on $x$ and as can be shown for this example it's : $x_2[n] = x[(-n)_N]$ when $W$ is the **unitary** DFT matrix. If that's what you want to ask...

Comment: @Fat32 I've reopened it, but it seems like a nonsense question.

Comment: @PeterK. you are actually right, but I hope she/he either **edits** the question so as to make any sense for a different answer or **accept** the already provided **correct** answer regarding the current position of the question...

Comment: @Fat32 I edit the question. Strang says $x = Wc$, and $x$ is the original signal, so it differs from DFT.. Do you know what I express?

Comment: Whether DFT or DWT or any other linear transform that are representable via **matrix** operations, if $X=Wx$ then $x=WX$ is **not** true unless $W^{-1}=W$ (which also implies $X=x$) and which is not the case for DFT as clearly stated by @MarcusMüller.

Comment: Yep , I grasp your point. But in the video lecture, Strang says $x = Wc$, is that not true? I think $x = W^{-1}c$ is true.@Fat32

Comment: @standerQiu note that the statement I made as $x=X$ is not true in general but only for the trivial case $W=I$...

Comment: I know  $W$ is not $I$ in general, but at least in the video they are not identical..@Fat32

Comment: @Fat32 By analog, wavelet coefficients $c$ should be $c = Wx$ like $X = Wx$ in DFT, but they are not in that video. So he is wrong, or me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Fourier matrix (which you refer to as Fourier basis matrix) is, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierMatrix.html), an $n\times n$ matrix with entries given by $\omega^{np}$ (with $\omega$ being the roots of unity). Here $n$ is the time index and $p$ is the frequency index.

Hence I think it's not reasonable to say that the Fourier matrix is either in the "**time space**" or the "**frequency space**" (or domain, if you like), since **it is in both**!

---

Also, there might be some confusion here due to the different meanings of the words like *space, domain, basis*, and *vector*, depending on the context.

So for linear algebra (from Wolfram MathWorld), we have:

- **(vector) space:** A vector space V is a set that is closed under finite vector addition and scalar multiplication. The basic example is $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $R^n$, where every element is represented by a list of $n$ real numbers, scalars are real numbers [...].
- **vector:** A vector is formally defined as an element of a vector space.
- **basis:** A basis of a vector space V is defined as a subset $v_1,...,v_n$ of vectors in V that are linearly independent and span V.

As for sigProc (from Wikipedia), we have:

- **[time / frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain):**  The time/frequency domain refers to the analysis of mathematical functions or signals with respect to time/frequency. Put simply, a time-domain graph shows how a signal changes over time, whereas a frequency-domain graph shows how much of the signal lies within each given frequency band over a range of frequencies.
- **(data) vector / 1D array:** In computer science, an array is a data structure consisting of a collection of elements, each identified by at least one array index or key.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @standerQiu Btw, the two $W$'s in your last comment are different... Also, you could force them into the same "(output) = (transformation matrix) x (input)" form if you wanted by writing $X=Wx$ for DFT and $c=(W^{-1})x$ for DWT (still different $W$ matrices tho)

Comment: Eventually I find an answer to my question! **Fourier matrix is either in the "time space" or the "frequency space" (or domain, if you like), since it is in both!**  Thx!!

Answer (score 4):

It's not valid.
If any matrix $W$ is invertible (such as the DFT matrix is), then there's the inverse $W^{-1}$ with

$$\begin{align}
W^{-1}W &=I\\
&\implies\\
X &= Wx \\
&\iff\\
W^{-1} X &= W^{-1}W x\\
&= Ix\\
&=x\text{ .}
\end{align}$$

Now, the Discrete Fourier transform can be defined to be unitary, so that its inverse

$$W^{-1}=W^*$$
is but the hermitian of the original transform.

In no case are the DFT and IDFT identical.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thanks! I had a bit of a bad conscience by giving an answer that had little more content then your comment under the question; but that was really something I needed to point out. If $W=W^{-1}$, then either $W$ would have to be real (which can't be, because of the various shift properties of the DFT, for example), or wouldn't have only positive Eigenvalues – which would be a disaster for Parseval's Theorem, for example.

Comment: @MarcusMüller My question is not that.. I know $x = W^{H}X$, but in mathematics,$X$ is in the space spanned by Fourier basis $W$, so $x$ should be the linear combination of Fourier basis and Fourier coefficients -> $x = WX$

Comment: @standerQiu, no. Simply, no. $x=W^{-1}X$ the way you defined it. Just because the span is the same doesn't mean the operation and its inverse are the same.

Comment: Or could you explain the validity of $X=Wx$ in the language of linear transformation?

Comment: You called $W$ the DFT base matrix. Hence, DFT, understood as linear transform, maps a vector $x$ to  $X$ and is given by $X=Wx$, as defined above.

Comment: You defined $X=Wx$. You shouldn't be arguing it. It's a definition.

Comment: But $x$ and $W$ are not in the same space... How could they make a linear transformation...

Comment: @standerQiu Is your problem that $x$ has units of time and $X$ has units of frequency? If so, note that the DFT operates on sequences of numbers (you could say, on "vectors") with no units. We assign units to those sequences somewhat arbitrarily; or put another way, we **interpret** $x$ as samples in time and $X$ as samples in frequency, but it's just an interpretation (that happens to be useful). $W$ has no units, either.

Comment: @MBaz I agree with what you said. But I confused in DWT and DFT, could you see the discussion below the question.?

Comment: @MBaz and stander, while the arguments of $x(t)$ and $X(f)$ have units of time or frequency (respectively), these are the content of the continuous Fourier Transform.  the DFT maps a set of dimensionless numbers, with dimensionless indices of integer value, from one domain (commonly called the "time domain") to another set of dimensionless numbers, also with dimensionless integer indices, in another domain (commonly called the "frequency domain").  the computer that crunches the numbers in the DFT has no idea of attached units.